# What the proper way of uploading an image in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a REST endpoint for creating certain resource, but now I want to add the functionality of uploading an image when creating the resource. What's the proper way of doing such feature? Do you need to upload the file separately then do another POST request for creating the resource?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not that good with Django, but I did this by using the form, and it works fine.

forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('brand', 'name', 'image', 'price',
              'warrenty', 'description', 'seller')
```

and in views.py

```
def merchant_product(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('merchant-product')

    else:
        print('Adding product failed from {}'.format(request.user.id))

return render(request, 'dashboard/merchant/product.html', {'form': ProductForm})
```

finally in the HTML file for the image field

```
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="{{form.image.name}}" required>
```

Make sure you are using FileField instead of ImageField for an image in models.py